# How to create desktop icon using Xcode

Tags: macos, icons, xcode

I want to create a desktop icon for my application so that when user installs the application, an application icon should be created on the desktop and allow the user to run the application from the desktop icon.

I know it is not a good practice and the user can create an icon on desktop or on the dock by dragging and dropping the application to the required place, but still I want to know how to achieve this.

I'm using Xcode Version 3.2.5.

Comment: I am using Xcode Version 3.2.5

Comment: What Abizern said. PLEASE don't do this; for educational purposes, it's okay, but IMO there are better ways to learn how to use aliases. ;) Also, if you REALLY had to do it, say for an enterprise deployment where the IT department demanded it (they do stupid things like that sometimes) you'd want to use PackageMaker to make an actual installer package instead of doing it on first run, but I don't know and don't care how to do it because once again it's terrible practice. EDIT: Just noticed Anne below mentioned the PackageMaker way. Again, see all the comments on terrible practice. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

Create the alias yourself like this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDesktopDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *deskPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSURL *appURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
NSURL *aliasURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[deskPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AppName"]];

NSError *err = nil;
NSData *bookmarkData = [appURL bookmarkDataWithOptions: NSURLBookmarkCreationSuitableForBookmarkFile includingResourceValuesForKeys:nil relativeToURL:nil error:&err];

if(bookmarkData == nil) {
    // Error
} else {
    if(![NSURL writeBookmarkData:bookmarkData toURL:aliasURL options:NSURLBookmarkCreationSuitableForBookmarkFile error:&err]) {
        // Error
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

Use NDAlias to create the alias:
http://homepage.mac.com/nathan_day/pages/source.xml

**Option 3**

PackageMaker features default post-installations-actions, including alias creation.

[image]

**Note**

It's frowned upon to create application aliases on the desktop.
Better add the application to the Dock during installation.